# How to persist java object in android

Tags: java, android

i'm using a library and each time i wanna use it `i have to login` first.and it takes some time to get the logged in `object` and that's not good.

i don't want to wait each time i open my app.

is there a way to keep this logged in object? (after closing app) can i keep this object in memory or disk or in `SharedPreferences` as String?

the target class has these fileds:

```
protected String deviceId;
private String username;
private String password;
protected boolean isLoggedIn;
private String uuid;
protected String rankToken;
private long userId;
protected Response lastResponse;
protected OkHttpClient client;
private final Set<Cookie> cookieStore = new HashSet();
```

if you have a solution please write a sample code as well.

i tried this sofar and didn't work:

```
String json = gson.toJson(insta,Target.class);
Target myTarget = gson.fromJson(json, Target.class);
```

and  `json` is empty.

Comment: if i get your question, then u can store it in database, or make a json with the data and put it in `SharedPreferences` and after starting the app parse from `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @SRBbans i tried `Gson` but didn't work ... would u please write a sample code?

Comment: @Mehrad the internet is full of examples, what have you tried exactly?

Comment: @SRBbans json equals { }

Comment: Please explain in further detail, what exactly did not work for you with Gson and SharedPreferences. Both APIs are very easy to use and there are plenty examples outside in the web. So please, at least, tell us what went wrong and post a readable stack trace and code.

Comment: I am slightly worried about "insta".

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using?
You can store season tokens if the library provides one.
Also, why not store the data in a database(local) and when a user launches the app you get the data from the database first while at the same time you do the login request in the background.Once you logged in just updated the data if it needs updating.

Comment: how to store and reCreate the object is the problem. @red_spark

Comment: You created a table in a database with columns that represent the data in your class.Example:deviceId, username, password(should not store passwords)....etc
After that, each row would represent a new object.So all you would have to do is get a desired row from the table and stick the values from it into your object class.
If you don't know how databases work you should read up on SQLite.
Alos here is how you make on in Android:https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways of persisting informations in Android.
But keep in mind that if you can easily persists simple types (`boolean`, `long`, `String`), you will have to determine which information is important to serialize for other types.

For instance, the `OkHttpClient` should not be persisted since it only is a web client and does not hold any valuable data.

Having said that you can work with one of the possibilities below:

- Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), this is simple key/value store in which you can store each field independantly.
- Use a database like [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), it requires more work to integrate it, but it can become handy if you have more data inthe future.
- Use java [Serialization](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), it will enable you to write the binary representation of your class in a file a retrieve it afterwards. But be wary of those `Response`,`OkHttpClient`, and `Cookie` classes which may not be serializable (requiring you to detach the serializable information from the others).